# when i creating custom block modules it is showing in modules list and activated fine. But not displaying in blocks list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

folder name: yourModule
In that folder i have two file..one file is "yourModule.info"....and another is "yourModule.module".

yourModule.info code:

```
;$ID$
name = "Your Module"
description = "Place to put PHP functions for Drupal customizations."
core = 7.x
```

yourModule.module code:

```
/*****************************************************************************
* Implementation of hook_block()
* @see http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_block/6
* create a minimal block
*/
function yourModule_block( $op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  switch ($op) {
  case 'list':
       // appears on the Blocks configuration page admin/build/block<br>
       $blocks = array();
       $blocks[0]['info'] = t('My Block');
       return $blocks;
  case 'view':
       // content of block; required to have 'subject' and 'content' elements
       $blocks = array();
       $blocks['subject'] = t('<center>My Block Status</center>');
       $blocks['content'] = t('<center>My Block Content</center>');
       return $blocks;
  }
}
```

I am searching google about this for 3 days byt no use..i am using drupal 7 and wamp on windows-xp...pls save me

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged the question as Drupal 7, and indeed your module's info file declares `core = 7.x`, but you're using the block hooks from Drupal 6.

For Drupal 7 you need to use [`hook_block_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [`hook_block_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) respectively.

```
function yourModule_block_info() {
  $blocks['my_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('My Block'), 
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function yourModule_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  if ($delta == 'my_block') {
    $block['subject'] = t('My Block Status');
    $block['content'] = t('My Block Content');
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hook_block() doesn't exist in drupal 7. Look [block.api.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/7) for further information.